# Induction, how often?

Tags: induction, natural-numbers, first-order-logic

I have the following definition:

$\quad p(x) \iff (x=0 \vee$
$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\exists y\ (x=y+2\ \&\ p(y)) \vee$
$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad(x=1\ \&\ \forall y\ p(y*2)))$

Assume I have first order logic with the 
first order induction principle for natural
numbers. Plus definitions for $+2$ and $*2$ bootstrapped
from successor.

Can I prove $\forall x\ p(x)$? And if yes, can I
do it with a single induction?

Answer (score 2):

Is this formal enough?

You have $p(0)$. Denoting the successor by $'$ we have $y'*2=(y*2)+2$. Therefore from $p(x)\Rightarrow p(x+2)$ we can conclude that $\forall y:\ p(y*2)$. This implies $p(1)$ by your third clause, and using $p(x)\Rightarrow p(x+2)$ again we get $p(x)$ for all odd $x$.

Comment: Greetings from CH to CH. Looks like an agreement that ∀x p(x) holds. But somehow the proof doesn't go through with a single induction over p, does it?

Comment: I'm not a logician, but it's obvious that one cannot get to odd numbers before $p$ is proven for all even numbers, since your third clause cannot be invoked before $p$ holds for all even numbers.

Comment: I have constructed the example from the property that ∀x doesn't preserve countable infinite ascending unions. The existential quantifier does so. But I am not yet sure what the implications are for induction. Maybe one can construct a predicate q, prove it by a single induction, and then derive p. Like following the odd numbers and hypothetically following the even numbers at the same time, and joining the two together resolving the hypothesis. The hypothesis would be p(1).